# Is there any way to call python code in android develop without installing sl4a?

Tags: java, android, python

I have found some ways to using python to build android app.But all of them need to install sl4a and pythonforandroid.
It is so complicated,so is there any way to package sl4a to my android app project,and once I install the apk,I needn't install sl4a any more.

Comment: Maybe it will help you to look at following topic : 

[How can I integrate a Python code in the Android Java app?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-integrate-a-Python-code-in-the-Android-Java-app)

And here is another good project that I think you should check: [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Kivy at following link :

[Python for Android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android)

It will can help u have a look to the following topic :

[How can I integrate a Python code in the Android Java app?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-integrate-a-Python-code-in-the-Android-Java-app)

hope this help you.

Comment: I just want to call some python scripts（most of codes of my project using Java）It seems that kivy isn't compatible well with java,and the UI is difference from native android app.

Comment: I have did some research, I don't know if this one could help you [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this. What it comes down to is packaging the Python interpreter (compiled by the NDK) in your app, and starting it via the standard NDK mechanisms. This is the same thing that e.g. Kivy does, but you'd be adding the code to your own app rather than (like Kivy) using a java bootstrap then letting the Python manage everything else.

One option, which has seen a little discussion/development recently, is to use [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) to build all the python components, then copy them into your java project (and add the code to handle it). This is possible, but not currently as easy as it could be, you'd need to look into how it works internally to get the outputs you need.

Another option that is probably easier right now if you don't need compiled code beyond python itself is to directly use the precompiled python binaries of the [CrystaX NDK](https://www.crystax.net/), in which case including the python binaries comes down to only adding them to your Android.mk. You'd still need some C and NDK code to interact with the interpreter, but the process is quite straightforward.

(SL4A has some Android build tools of its own, which you could also use for this, but I don't know what you'd need to do to integrate it as I think SL4A does extra things on top of just having the python interpreter present).

Comment: I just find one blog which refered to python.https://www.crystax.net/en/blog/6    ,is there more articles or demo about this?

Comment: Not really, though for what it's worth the individual steps are fairly standard. You can look at python-for-android's python3 support for an example of using crystax's binaries, but this will also be hard to get into as it's tied up with a lot of other functionality.